# Is there something like http://www.django-userena.org/ in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, user-interface

IS there something like http://www.django-userena.org/ in Rails 3. I'm programmer and not UI guy but I want to write an App (convert my idea into real product). Could I get readymade UI somewhere for Rails 3 App?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at activeadmin maybe ?
http://activeadmin.info/